# TensorFlow how to correctly build a batch of imput data: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train a cnn with my own image (currently I've been drawing 900*900 gray scale images with PIL with the following code). I used the loop to make a few at a time cuz I'm not sure if I need to send several in as a batch or not.

```
def nextBrains():
X_dataset = np.array([])
Y_dataset = np.array([])

for i in range(10):
    im = Image.new( "L", (900,900),color = "black")
    dr = ImageDraw.Draw( im )

    x1 = rd.randrange(0,450,1)
    y1 = rd.randrange(0,450,1)
    x2 = rd.randrange(x1,450,1)
    y2 = rd.randrange(y1,450,1)

    sx = rd.randrange(0,2,1) *250
    sy = rd.randrange(0,2,1) *250

    if ( sx == 0 and sy == 0) : Y = 1
    if ( sx == 250 and sy == 0) : Y = 2
    if ( sx == 0 and sy == 250) : Y = 3
    if ( sx == 250 and sy == 250) : Y = 4

    dr.ellipse((x1+sx,y1+sy,x2+sx,y2+sy), fill = 'white', outline ='white')

    image = np.asarray(im)
    X = image.reshape(1,900,900,1)

    X = tf.convert_to_tensor( X, dtype = tf.float32)
    Y = tf.convert_to_tensor( Y, dtype = tf.int32)

    X_dataset = np.append( X_dataset, X )
    Y_dataset = np.append( Y_dataset, Y)

return X_dataset, Y_dataset
```

the placeholder I use is as following: (I just started so most of this is directly from tutorial example)

```
height = 900
width = 900
channels = 1
n_inputs = height * width

with tf.name_scope("inputs"):
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, height, width, channels ], name="X")
X_reshaped = tf.reshape(X, shape=[-1, height, width, channels])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None], name="y")
```

and when I run

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
init.run()
batch_size = 100

with tf.Session() as sess:
init.run()


for epoch in range(n_epochs):   
    for iteration in range(100):
        X_batch, y_batch = nextBrains()
        sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
    acc_train = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
    acc_test = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={X: X_batch, y: y_batch})
    print(epoch, "Train accuracy:", acc_train, "Test accuracy:", acc_test)
```

I got this error for the "feed_dict" line:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

I've tried a few times and able to resolved this shape error

> ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (8100000,) for Tensor
>   'inputs/X:0', which has shape '(?, 900, 900, 1)'

I would like to know how to correctly build a batch of X and Y so that the code could run without either of the error.

Thanks a lot